# How can I get a JSON listing of a particular Soundcloud user's posts?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, soundcloud

I'm trying to tie together some social media to a single page. Is there a way of getting Soundcloud data for a user without logging in? Like, say, metadata of their last-X posts?

Answer (score 1):

Soundcloud has an API which lets you get information on a user. Documentation can be found here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first register your app to the soundcloud API to get a key. Then you `curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"` which will return a JSON [formatted like so](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users). Then you use it however you want :-)